# Adding mapview or any other view to detailViewController of Master-Detail View application without using Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

How can I add a mapview or a webview to a detail view of a master-detail view application?

I created the mapview using the following code...

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
    [_detailItem release];
    _detailItem = [newDetailItem retain];

    // Update the view.


    //CREATE MAPVIEW
    mView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    mView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = { 61.2180556, -149.9002778};
    MKCoordinateSpan span = {0.2, 0.2};
    MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};

    [mView setRegion:region];

    //MAPVIEW CREATED

    [self configureView];

   }
```

Now, I used the following code to display it in the detail view:

```
- (void)configureView
{
// Update the user interface for the detail item.

if (self.detailItem) {
    [self.view addSubview:mView];
    }

}
```

But this is not loading the mapview in the detail view.

I want to achieve this with code and without using Interface Builder to drop a map view and then linking it with an IBOutlet.

I suppose the following line of code should have helped.

```
[self.view addSubview:mView];
```